# Adding additional parameters to mail() using CI email class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to find a way to add additional parameters to an email using Codeigniters email class (with the mail() send method). There is no documentation or other information I can find. Do you folks know if there is a way within the framework?

PHP native mail():

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers 
       [, string $additional_parameters ]] );
```

Codeigniter:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->additional_parameters('something_goes_here'); // this is what I need
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: do you mean additional mail headers ?

Comment: No, additional parameters, the fifth parameter to the php mail() function

Comment: you should use smtp, not mail unless there's a good reason not to. `$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';`

Comment: sure, I have a good reason... Server has a quite specific network config. SMTP doesn't work right now anyway.

Comment: then your stuck with out editing some core codeigniter files. mail() is poor limited function. directly writing to the smtp server is always the best option.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks. Hmm, I guess it ends up there... But extending it or just write my own email class might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [CodeIgniter's Email Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) is just a wrapper for PHP's [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

If you dig into the core and inspect `system/libraries/Email.php`, `_send_with_mail()` is the function that kicks-off PHP's native `mail()`.

The current implementation under safe mode uses:

```
mail($this->_recipients, $this->_subject, $this->_finalbody, $this->_header_str)
```

The current implmentation without safe mode uses:

```
mail($this->_recipients, $this->_subject, $this->_finalbody, $this->_header_str, "-f ".$this->clean_email($this->_headers['From'])
```

Neither of which allow *user-defined content* to fill the `$additional_parameters` variable. You'll need to extend the `CI_Email` class to accomplish this:

In `application/libraries/` create a file `MY_Email.php` with contents:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Email extends CI_Email{
    public $additional_params = "";
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function additional_params($ap){
        $this->additional_params = $ap;
    }

    protected function _send_with_mail(){
        if ($this->_safe_mode == TRUE){
            if ( ! mail($this->_recipients, $this->_subject, $this->_finalbody, $this->_header_str, $this->additional_params)) return FALSE;
            else return TRUE;
        }
        else{
                if ( ! mail($this->_recipients, $this->_subject, $this->_finalbody, $this->_header_str, "-f ".$this->clean_email($this->_headers['From']) . " " . $this->additional_params)) return FALSE;
                else return TRUE;
        }
    }    


}
```

### Now, to use it:

`$this->email->additional_params('something_goes_here');`

When you call `$this->email->send()`, this function will take over and append the parameters!

Haven't tested any of this. But this is the general idea. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, just what I thought! Great coding for me anyway, I was just looking into the Email library trying to find my way there.... :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use the php mail() function. A framework doesn't means you must use every function from the framework.

Comment: Thanks, of course you're right about that. However when you run into problems often there is already solutions within the current framework. Writing my own email class around mail() is of course time consuming also if there is a easier solution.